# Fluent NHibernate Correctly map readonly property from base class

Tags: c#, list, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, readonly-collection

I want to create a base class for some of my entities, since they all share a `Event` list property.
I want also to make the `Event` list **a readonly property**.

So I created a base `EventRelatedEntity` class and then derived it on each of my entity class that has to do with Events.

Please also note that `EventRelatedEntity` class has no NHibernate mapping class since it's not linked to a table.

See code below.

**Base class:**

```
public class EventRelatedEntity
{
    private readonly List<Event> events;

    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<Event> Events { get; protected set; }

    public EventRelatedEntity()
    {
        events = new List<Event>();
        Events = events.AsReadOnly();
    }

    protected virtual void AddEvent<T>(T entity, string message)
    {
        if (events == null)
            events = new List<Event>();

        Event newEvent = new Event();

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Company))
        {
            newEvent.CompanyId = (entity as Company).Id;
            // ...and do some other stuff...
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Document))
        {
            newEvent.DocumentId = (entity as Document).Id;
            // ...and do some other stuff...
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Typology))
        {
            newEvent.TypologyId = (entity as Typology).Id;
            // ...and do some other stuff...
        }

        newEvent.Message = message;

        events.Add(newEvent);
    }
}
```

**Entity classes**

```
public class Company : EventRelatedEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Alias { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    // ...and some other properties...

    #region Actions

    public virtual void AddEvent(string message)
    {
        base.AddEvent(this, message);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Document : EventRelatedEntity
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; protected set; }
    // ...and some other properties...

    #region Actions

    public virtual void AddEvent(string message)
    {
        base.AddEvent(this, message);
    }

    #endregion
}

// ...and some other classes...
```

**Fluent NHibernate mapping classes for entities**

```
public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        Table("Companies");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.Alias).Column("Alias").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CompanyName).Column("CompanyName").Not.Nullable();
        // ...and some other mappings...

        // Link with Events table
        HasMany(x => x.Events) // Events is declared in the base class (EventRelatedEntity)
            .KeyColumn("CompanyId")
            .Access.LowerCaseField()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class DocumentMap : ClassMap<Document>
{   
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Table("Documents");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        References(x => x.User).Column("UserId");
        // ...and some other mappings...

        // Link with Events table
        HasMany(x => x.Events) // Events is declared in the base class (EventRelatedEntity)
            .KeyColumn("DocumentId")
            .Access.LowerCaseField()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

// ...and some other mapping classes...
```

Finally I want to avoid direct access to the `List<>.Add()` method. I want a readonly collection. The only way to add a new `Event` to the Event list of an entity must be the `AddEvent` method of the corresponding entity class.

Example:

```
Document document = session.Get<Document>(1);
// ...the same for other derived classes...

// I WANT TO AVOID THIS!
document.Events.Add(new Event());
// WANTS TO BE THE ONLY PERMITTED WAY TO ADD NEW EVENTS
document.AddEvent("My new event message");
```

The problem is that when I do the:

```
Document document = session.Get<Document>(1);
```

I get an error from NHibernate:

> Cannot cast objects of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag'1 [SolutionDOC_Interface.Entity.Event]' to the 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1 [SolutionDOC_Interface.Entity.Event]' type.

I think it is related with the fact the `EventRelatedEntity` class has no NHibernate mapping, but I can't provide a map, since it has not to do with a table in DB.
Maybe if I declare the Event list inside each class (Company, Document, etc.) without using inheritance, NHibernate will work, but this approach would produce quite a bit of code duplication that I want to avoid.

**UPDATE 2017/10/18**

After changing the code like @ryan suggested, now it works.

**Revised code:**

```
public class EventRelatedEntity
{
    private readonly IList<Event> events;

    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<Event> Events { get; protected set; }

    public EventRelatedEntity()
    {
        events = new List<Event>();
        Events = (events as List<Event>).AsReadOnly();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: so whats the problem? If `Events` is indeed declared as an `IReadOnlyCollection`, then `document.Events.Add(new Event());` should be producing an error: `'IReadOnlyCollection<Event>' does not contain a definition for 'Add'...`

Comment: I get a NHibernate error. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the list interface instead of the concrete list class, then the cast of `NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag` should work.

Use `IList<Event>` instead of `List<Event>` so `EventRelatedEntity` becomes:

```
public class EventRelatedEntity
{
    private readonly IList<Event> events;

    // rest of implementation...
}
```